# What is Facebook Insights section not totalling post likes correctly?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-comments, facebook-insights

I have a Facebook page that is getting a lot of likes and is in the process of building momentum.

https://www.facebook.com/GratePic-1720858451461996/

However, under the Insights tab, the post likes are not being totaled correctly. For example, I have one post that I shared in different groups that received hundreds of likes, but in the insights section, it is only showing that it received 12 likes…

I have tried using different browsers, clearing all of the caches in each browser, using different machines, etc…but this problem still persists. 
Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be a programming question. For Facebook end user support, please consult their Help section.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **customer support** question. [Why customer support questions are off-topic here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) .